# фильтр от gridview говорит что значение занято

Tags: yii2

Собственно вопрос в названии: есть модель, без связанных и вычисляемых полей, генерировалась через Gii. Если в фильтре по полю 'name' задать значение поиска, допустим "Квиллинг", то фильтр вместо того, чтобы отфильтровать, выдаёт "Значение «Квиллинг» для «Название» уже занято".

`[['name'], 'safe']` в `rules()` присутствует. Код стандартный, поэтому не выкладываю.

Как я понимаю, это отрабатывает валидатор. Но почему и зачем. Что именно его вызывает и как побороть?

Вот GridView

```
        <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'boxUnderTitle' => [
            Html::a('Создать категорию', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']),
        ],
        'columns' => [
            [
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:5%'],
                'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => ['width' => '3%']],
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'id',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => ['width' => '3%']],
                'value' => function ($model) {
                     return $model->id;
                 },
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'parent_id',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => ['width' => '12%'], 'class' => 'small'],
                'value' => function ($model) {
                     return $model->getName($model->parent_id).'<br>('.$model->parent_id.')';
                 },
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'name',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                     return Html::a($model->name, yii::$app->params['mainhost'].'/categories/'.$model->alias,['target' => '_blank']);
                 },
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'countProducts',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                     return Html::a($model->getCountProducts(), '/product/index?ProductSearch[category_id]='.$model->id,['target' => '_blank']);
                 },
            ],

//            [
//                'attribute' => 'countPages',
//                'value' => function($model){
//                    $res = $model->getCountPages($model->id);
//                    return $res;
//                }
//            ],
//            'landings',
            'meta_title',
            'meta_keywords',
            'meta_description',
            'h1',
            [
                'attribute' => 'description',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:12%', 'class' => 'small'],
                'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'middle'],
                'value' => function($model){
                    if($model->description) : $res = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_COMPLETED.'">description: есть</span>' ; else : $res = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_DELETE.'">description: нет</span>'; endif;
                    if($model->description1) : $res1 = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_COMPLETED.'">description1: есть</span>' ; else : $res1 = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_DELETE.'">description1: нет</span>'; endif;
                    if($model->description2) : $res2 = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_COMPLETED.'">description2: есть</span>' ; else : $res2 = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_DELETE.'">description2: нет</span>'; endif;
                    if($model->description3) : $res3 = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_COMPLETED.'">description3: есть</span>' ; else : $res3 = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_DELETE.'">description3: нет</span>'; endif;
                    if($model->description4) : $res4 = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_COMPLETED.'">description4: есть</span>' ; else : $res4 = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_DELETE.'">description4: нет</span>'; endif;
                    if($model->description5) : $res5 = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_COMPLETED.'">description5: есть</span>' ; else : $res5 = '<span style="color:'.ColorHelper::STATUS_DELETE.'">description5: нет</span>'; endif;
                    return $res.'<br>'.$res1.'<br>'.$res2.'<br>'.$res3.'<br>'.$res4.'<br>'.$res5;
                }
            ],
            [
//                'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'visibleButtons' => [
                    'view' => true,
                    'update' => true,
                    'delete' => function ($url,$model) {
                        /** @var $model common\models\Categories */
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"/>',Url::toRoute(['delete','id'=>$model->id]),['title'=>'Удалить']);
                    },
//                    'delete'=>function ($model)use($searchModel) {
//                    /** @var $model common\models\Categories */
//                     $cat =  $searchModel::findOne($model->id);
//                    return $cat->hasCategoryProduct($model->id);
//                    }
                ]
            ],
//            [
//                'buttons' => [
//                    'view' => function ($url,$model) {
//                        /** @var $model common\models\Categories */
//                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"/>',Url::toRoute(['view',
//                            'id'=>$model->id]),['title'=>'Просмотр']);
//                    },
//                    'update' => function ($url,$model) {
//                        /** @var $model common\models\Categories */
//                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/>',Url::toRoute(['update',
//                            'id'=>$model->id]),['title'=>'Редактировать']);
//                    },
//                    'delete' => function ($url,$model) {
//                        /** @var $model common\models\Categories */
//                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"/>',Url::toRoute(['delete',
//                            'id'=>$model->id]),['title'=>'Удалить']);
//                    },
//                ],
//            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Вот модель

```
<?php

namespace common\models;
use common\components\MenuTree;
use yii\behaviors\SluggableBehavior;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\VarDumper;
use common\models\LandingPagesCategories;
use yii;

/**
 * Categories model
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $parent_id
 * @property integer $fee_service
 * @property integer $fee_seller
 * @property string $alias
 * @property string $name
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 * @property integer $level
 */

class Categories extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    const DEFAULT_CATEGORY = 'system';
    const GROUP_YES = 1;
    const GROUP_NO = 0;

    public $level;
    public $names = [];
    public $min_price = 0;
    public $landings = [];

    public $isGroup = [
        self::GROUP_YES => 'Групповая категория',
        self::GROUP_NO => 'Категория для товара',
    ];

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
                'attribute' => 'name',
                'slugAttribute' => 'alias',
                'immutable' => true,
                'ensureUnique'=>true,

            ],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%categories}}';
    }



    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [
                [
                    'id',
                    'parent_id',
                    'groups',
                    'fee_service',
                    'fee_seller',
                    'name',
                    'alias',
                    'created_at',
                    'updated_at',
                    'names',
                    'landings',
                    'meta_title',
                    'meta_keywords',
                    'meta_description',
                    'h1',
                    'description',
                    'description1',
                    'description2',
                    'description3',
                    'description4',
                    'description5',
//                    'countProducts',
                ], 'safe'
            ],
            ['name','unique'],
//            [['parent_id','name'],'required'],
            [['meta_title', 'meta_description', 'meta_keywords', 'h1'], 'string'],
            [['description','description1', 'description2','description3','description4','description5'], 'string'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => \Yii::t('app','ID'),
            'parent_id' => \Yii::t('app','Родитель'),
            'groups' => Yii::t('app','Содержит другие категории, не содержит товар'),
            'fee_service' => \Yii::t('app','% Системы'),
            'fee_seller' => \Yii::t('app','% Продавца'),
            'alias' => \Yii::t('app','Алиас'),
            'name' => \Yii::t('app','Название'),
            'created_at' => \Yii::t('app','Создание'),
            'updated_at' => \Yii::t('app','Обновление'),
            'description' => Yii::t('app', 'Описание для страницы без page').' '.yii::t('app','count_symbols').': '.iconv_strlen(strip_tags($this->description)),
            'description1' => Yii::t('app', 'Описание для page1').' '.yii::t('app','count_symbols').': '.iconv_strlen(strip_tags($this->description1)),
            'description2' => Yii::t('app', 'Описание для page2').' '.yii::t('app','count_symbols').': '.iconv_strlen(strip_tags($this->description2)),
            'description3' => Yii::t('app', 'Описание для page3').' '.yii::t('app','count_symbols').': '.iconv_strlen(strip_tags($this->description3)),
            'description4' => Yii::t('app', 'Описание для page4').' '.yii::t('app','count_symbols').': '.iconv_strlen(strip_tags($this->description4)),
            'description5' => Yii::t('app', 'Описание для page5').' '.yii::t('app','count_symbols').': '.iconv_strlen(strip_tags($this->description5)),
            'countProducts' => Yii::t('app','Кол товаров'),
            'meta_title' => Yii::t('app','meta_title').' '.yii::t('app','ValueForNumberPage'),
            'meta_keywords' => Yii::t('app','meta_keywords').' '.yii::t('app','ValueForNumberPage'),
            'meta_description' => Yii::t('app','meta_description').' '.yii::t('app','ValueForNumberPage'),
            'h1' => Yii::t('app','h1').' '.yii::t('app','ValueForNumberPage'),
        ];
    }
    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Categories::find()->with(['products']);

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort' => [
                'attributes' => [
                    'id',
                    'parent_id',
                    'groups',
                    'fee_service',
                    'fee_seller',
                    'name',
                    'alias',
                    'created_at',
                    'updated_at',
                    'names',
                    'landings',
                    'meta_title',
                    'meta_keywords',
                    'meta_description',
                    'h1',
                    'description',
                    'description1',
                    'description2',
                    'description3',
                    'description4',
                    'description5',

                ],
                'defaultOrder' => ['id' => SORT_ASC]
            ]
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            $query->joinWith(['products']);
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parent_id', $this->parent_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fee_service', $this->fee_service])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fee_seller', $this->fee_seller])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
//            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'alias', $this->alias])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'created_at', strtotime($this->created_at)])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'updated_at', strtotime($this->updated_at)]);
        return $dataProvider;
    }
    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUserCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserCategories::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getMainCategory(){
        return self::findOne(['parent_id'=>$this->id]);
    }

    public function getParentCategory(){
        return self::findOne(['id'=>$this->parent_id])->with('products.provider','products.user');
    }

    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
    }
//    public function getProductsCount()
//    {
//        return $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['category_id' => 'id'])
//                ->count();
//    }
//    public function getProductsCountVisible()
//    {
//        return $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['category_id' => 'id'])
//                ->Where(['visible' => 1])
//                ->count();
//    }


    public function getCategoryFeeService(){
        if($this->parent_id === 0){
            $fee_service = $this->fee_service;
        }else{
            if($this->fee_service != null){
                $fee_service = $this->fee_service;
            }else{
                $mainCategories = Categories::findOne($this->parent_id);
                $fee_service = $mainCategories->fee_service;
            }
        }
        return $fee_service;
    }
    public function getCategoryFeeSeller($order = false){        

        if($order && $order->provider->isOperationByPayment() && $order->provider->reward_percent!=0){
            return $order->provider->reward_percent;
        }else{
            if($this->parent_id === 0){
                $fee_seller = $this->fee_seller;
            }else{
                if($this->fee_seller != null){
                    $fee_seller = $this->fee_seller;
                }else{
                    $mainCategories = Categories::findOne($this->parent_id);
                    $fee_seller = $mainCategories->fee_seller;
                }
            }
            return $fee_seller;
            }
    }

    public function getMainCategoriesForAdmin(){
        $arr[0] = 'Главная';
        foreach (Categories::find()->asArray()->all() as $v){
            $arr[$v['id']] = $v['name'];
        }
        return $arr;
    }
    public function getMainCategories($createCat = false,$hasProduct = false,$target = null){
        $catsIdWithoutProd  = [];
        $arrCats = Categories::find()->asArray()->all();
        if($target != null) {
            $categoryTree = new MenuTree($arrCats);
            $categoryTree->build();
            $tree = $categoryTree->getItemsTree();
            $targetChain = [];
            $targetChain = $this->find_node($tree,$target);
            $kickIds[] = $target;
            $kickIds = $this->find_node_keys($kickIds,$targetChain);
        }

        foreach ($arrCats as $index=>$value){
            if($target != null) {
                if (in_array($value['id'], $kickIds)) {
                    unset($arrCats[$index]);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if($hasProduct == true){
                if(Product::find()->where(['category_id'=>$value['id']])->count() > 0  && !in_array($value['id'], $catsIdWithoutProd))
                    $catsIdWithoutProd[] = $value['id'];
            }else {
                if(Product::find()->where(['category_id'=>$value['id']])->count() == 0 && !in_array($value['id'], $catsIdWithoutProd))
                    $catsIdWithoutProd[] = $value['id'];
            }
        }
        if($hasProduct != 'all')
            $cats = Categories::find()->where(['id'=>$catsIdWithoutProd])->asArray()->all();
        else
            $cats = $arrCats;
//

        $categoryTree = new MenuTree($cats);
        $categoryTree->build();
        $tree = $categoryTree->getItemsTree();

        if($createCat) $result[0] = 'Главная';
//        VarDumper::dump($tree,1000,true);die();

        $result = $this->getBuildTreeList($result,'',$tree);
       return $result;
    }

    public function getMainCategories2(){

        $res = $this->find()->where(['!=' , 'groups', self::GROUP_NO])->asArray()->all();
        $res = ArrayHelper::map($res, 'id', 'name');
        $res[0] = '---';
        return $res;

    }

    public function hasProducts(){
        return Product::find()->where(['category_id'=>$this->id])->exists();
    }

    public function getBuildTreeList(&$result,$parentName = '',$categories) {
        foreach ($categories as $i=>$cat){
            if($cat['parent_id'] == 0 ) $parentName = $cat['name'];
            $oldParentName = $parentName;
            if(isset($cat['children']) && count($cat['children'])){
                if($parentName == $cat['name'] && $cat['parent_id'] == 0) {
                    $result[$i] =$cat['name'];
                }
                elseif($parentName !== '' && $cat['parent_id'] !== 0) {
                    $parentName .= ' / '.$cat['name'];
                    $result[$i] =  $parentName;
                }
                foreach ($cat['children'] as $id=>$child){
                    self::getBuildTreeList($result,$parentName,$cat['children']);
                }
                $parentName = $oldParentName;
            }else{
                if($parentName == $cat['name'])
                    $result[$i] =$cat['name'];
                elseif($parentName !== '' && $parentName !== $cat['name'])
                    $result[$i] = $parentName.' / '.$cat['name'];
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getSubCategories(){

        $result = $this->getMainCategories(false,'all');
        $result[100000] = Yii::t('app', 'not-sel-cat');
        foreach ($result as $id=>$cat ){
            if(Categories::find()->where(['parent_id'=>$id])->exists())
                unset($result[$id]);
        }
//        VarDumper::dump($result,1000,true);
       return $result;
    }

    public function hasSubCategories(){

        $categoryTree = new MenuTree(Categories::find()->asArray()->all());
        $categoryTree->build();
        $tree = $categoryTree->getItemsTree();

        $targetChainProd = $this->find_node($tree,$this->id);
        $productCatIds[] = $this->id;
        $productCatIds = $this->find_node_keys($productCatIds,$targetChainProd);

//        VarDumper::dump($productCatIds,100,true);die();
        if (count($productCatIds) >1) {
            return true;
        }elseif(count($productCatIds) == 1){
            return false;
        }

//        VarDumper::dump(count($productCatIds),100,true);die();
    }

    public function treeForAdminCategory(){
        $categoryTree = new MenuTree(Categories::find()->asArray()->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_ASC])->all());
        $categoryTree->build();
        $tree = $categoryTree->getItemsTree();
        $categories = [];
        foreach (Categories::find()->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_ASC])->all() as $c){
            $categories[$c->id] = $c;
        }
        $result = [];
        $result = $this->getTreeForViewAdmin($result, $tree);
        $r = [];
        foreach ($result as $val){
            $item = $categories[$val['id']];
            $item->level = $val['level'];
            $r[$val['id']] = $item;
        }
        return $r;

    }

    private function getTreeForViewAdmin(&$result,$dataset,$level = 1)
    {
        foreach ($dataset as $id => $child) {
            $item = $child;
            unset($item['children']);
            $item['level'] = $level;
            $result[] =[
                'id'=>$item['id'],
                'level'=>$level
            ];
            if (isset($child['children']) && count($child['children'])){
                $this->getTreeForViewAdmin($result,$child['children'],$level + 1);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function hasCategoryProduct($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findOne($id);

        $categoryTree = new MenuTree(Categories::find()->asArray()->all());
        $categoryTree->build();
        $tree = $categoryTree->getItemsTree();

        $targetChainProd = $this->find_node($tree,$model->id);
        $productCatIds[] = $model->id;
        $productCatIds = $this->find_node_keys($productCatIds,$targetChainProd);

        $cats = Categories::findAll($productCatIds);
        $userCats = [];
        foreach ($cats as $cat){
            $usrCats = $cat->userCategories;
            foreach ($usrCats as $usrCat){
                if(!in_array($usrCat->id,$userCats) && $usrCat->id !== null)
                    $userCats[] = $usrCat->id;
            }
            unset($usrCats);
        }

        if((count($productCatIds) == 1) && (Product::find()->where(['category_id'=>$productCatIds])->count() == 0) && (count($userCats) == 0))   {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    public function findAllParentsCat(&$result,$dataset,$targetId){
        if(isset($dataset[$targetId]['parent_id']) && $dataset[$targetId]['parent_id'] != 0 ){
            foreach ($dataset as $cat){
                if($cat['id'] == $targetId){
                    $result[] = $cat['parent_id'];
                    $this->findAllParentsCat($result,$dataset,$cat['parent_id']);
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function find_node_keys(&$result,$dataset) {
        if(isset($dataset['children']) && count($dataset['children'])){
            foreach ($dataset['children'] as $id=>$child){
                $result[] = $id;
                self::find_node_keys($result,$child);
            }
        }else{
            if(!in_array((int)$dataset['id'],$result))
                $result[] = (int)$dataset['id'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
    public function find_node(&$dataset,$id) {
        if(isset($dataset[$id])) return $dataset[$id];
        foreach ($dataset as $value){
            if (isset($value['children'])) {
                $result=self::find_node($value['children'], $id);
                if ($result) return $result;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getUrl()
    {
        return Url::toRoute(['categories/index', 'alias' => $this->alias]);
    }
    public function getParentCategoriesIds(){
        $arr = [];
        foreach (Categories::find()->asArray()->all() as $cat){
            $arr[$cat['id']]['id'] = $cat['id'];
            $arr[$cat['id']]['parent_id'] = $cat['parent_id'];
            $arr[$cat['id']]['name'] = $cat['name'];
        }
        $list = [];
        $list = self::findAllParentsCat($list,$arr,$this->id);
        return $list;
    }

    public function save($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = null){

        if (!empty($this->landings)) {
            $all = ArrayHelper::index(LandingPagesCategories::find()->select(["landing_id"])->where(['category_id'=>$this->id])->asArray()->all(),'landing_id');
            foreach($this->landings as $lend){
                if(!LandingPagesCategories::find()->where(['category_id'=>$this->id,'landing_id'=>$lend])->exists()){
                    $new_prod = new LandingPagesCategories();
                    $new_prod->category_id = $this->id;
                    $new_prod->landing_id = $lend;
                    $new_prod->created_at = time();
                    $new_prod->save();
                }
                unset($all[$lend]);
            }
            foreach($all as $al){
                LandingPagesCategories::find()->where(['category_id'=>$this->id,"landing_id"=>$al['landing_id']])->one()->delete();
            }
        }
        return parent::save($runValidation, $attributeNames);
    }

    public function lendingList()
    {
        $this->landings = ArrayHelper::getColumn(LandingPagesCategories::find()->where(['category_id'=>$this->id])->asArray()->all(),'landing_id');
        return \common\models\LandingPages::List();
    }

    public function getDefoultCategory(){        
        return self::findOne(['name'=>self::DEFAULT_CATEGORY])->id;
    }

    public function getCountProducts() {
        $products = $this->products;
        return ($products) ? count($products) : 0;
    }

    public function getName($id) {
        $res = Categories::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
        return $res->name;
    }
}
```

Вот контроллер

```
public function actionSeo()
{
    $searchModel = new Categories();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('seo', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Покажи свой 'gridview'

Comment: выложил код вьюхи, модели, контроллера

Comment: покажи свою модель полностью

Answer (score 0):

У тебя поле name required. Попробуй убери это правило

Comment: эта строчка у меня заккоментирована, но даже если бы и не была закомментирована, то как в таком случае сделать сделать поле обязательным, если валидатор по нему необходимо выключить ?

Comment: тут, собственно играет значение строчка ['name','unique']. Вот её если убрать, то норм становится, но мне реально нужен этот валидатор при создании категорий. Зачем вообще валидатор включается в фильтрах и как это отключить именно в них?

Comment: Вообще делается отдельная модель для поиска